# Removing all prefixed specified char and postfix space

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have have to compare two `char(4)`, which are formatted differently. Thus I would like to one format so that it can be compared to the other. Basically I need to remove prefixed zeros and trailing space if present.

For instance:

The chars:

`'001 '` and `'1'` should both compare to `'1'` after formatting

`'001A'` and `'1A'` should both compare to `'1A'` after formatting

`'010 '` and `'10'` should both compare to `'10'` after formatting

`'010A'` and `'10A'` should both compare to `'10A'` after formatting

`'100 '` and `'100'` should both compare to `'100'` after formatting

`'100A'` should compare to `'100A'` after formatting

```
select Replace(Ltrim(Replace(Rtrim(@charToBeFormatted), '0', ' ')), ' ', '0')
```

seems to work, but feels wasteful to replace strings twice and it really does not make the intention clear at all.

Can the result be achieved in a more efficient and/or elegant manner?

Comment: @Benoit [LTRIM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177827.aspx) and [RTRIM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178660.aspx) do not take a second parameter.

Comment: @JoeStefanelli eh, not sure what you mean. Both LTRIM and RTRIM in the example takes only one parameter. Can you elaborate? (maybe a underlining the of the mentioned problem with lack of readability/clear intention? ?_? )

Comment: I was responding to a commment posted by @Benoit, which he has since deleted.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing leading zeroes from a field in a SQL statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92093/removing-leading-zeroes-from-a-field-in-a-sql-statement)

Comment: Here's another one: [Algorithms to trim leading zeroes from a SQL field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457603/algorithms-to-trim-leading-zeroes-from-a-sql-field)

Comment: @AndriyM Thanks, I couldn't find the right keywords to search for I guess. I've voted to close as dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92093/removing-leading-zeroes-from-a-field-in-a-sql-statement

Answer (score 1):

is the result supposed to be a number? than you can do something like this:
select convert(int,'0010 ')

Comment: no, it is not supposed to be a number. The char '1A' does not make sense in my problem as an int.

Comment: that's right, I missed that. Did you see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92093/removing-leading-zeroes-from-a-field-in-a-sql-statement? reworking it you can make your query a little nicer: declare @var varchar(20)='0010 '
select Rtrim(RIGHT(@var,patindex('%[^0]%',@var)))