# Removing leading zeros in SSIS

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, trim, dts, leading-zero

I process data from a legacy system with SSIS before importing data into a SQL Server 2008 db.
A currency field is so formatted:

```
000000xxx.xx
```

I need to remove the leading zeros. Note that the actual currency value has not a fixed number of digit. So, for instance,  it could be xxxxx.xx or x.xx or xxxxxxxxxxx.xx

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457603/algorithms-to-trim-leading-zeroes-from-a-sql-field), but the derived column tool display only limited string functions, like the Access formula wizard.

So my question:

- how may I use PATINDEX in the DTS derived column tool
- otherwise, how may I remove leading zeros from input column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how are you querying the data? I suppose you are using direct table access on your OleDBSource component, right? I do not advise that because a tiny change on the table may break your package.

I would right a view containing the select from your source table and on this select I would use the PATINDEX function and inside the package, I would select the view instead of the table.

This is a good approach because if you need to do a minor change, you can change the view instead of the package

If you dont want to write a view, fine, instead of selecting "data access mode" = "table or view", select "sql command" and write your sql directly on the package.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding or misinterpreting your response. I don't think a view solves this problem, as a change to the view also breaks the OLE DB Source in a Data Flow Task.

Comment: but nothing is broken! he only has the data on a wrong format. want Im suggesting is correcting the data before it gets to SSIS, which means sourcing the data with a view and in it, use whatever method necessary to set the data on the necessary format

Answer (score 0):

Are you not able to cast the data into a numeric equivalent type in the source system? That should be a quick way to drop the leading zeros. `SELECT CAST(myCurrency AS decimal(18,2)) AS leadingZerosDropped FROM myTable`

Otherwise, the dead simple SSIS way to do it is to use a Data Conversion task and cast it to a numeric type (DT_CY/Currency or DT_Numeric/Numeric worked just fine)

### Source query

```
SELECT '000000111.11' AS stringCurrency
UNION ALL SELECT '0.22'
UNION ALL SELECT '03.33'
UNION ALL SELECT '004.44'
UNION ALL SELECT '0005.55'
UNION ALL SELECT '00000000000000000006.66'
```

### Data Conversion transformation

I created a new column, currencyCurrency which was the stringCurrency with a data type of currency [DT_CY] applied.

### Results

```
stringCurrency            currencyCurrency
000000111.11              111.11
0.22                      0.22
03.33                     3.33
004.44                    4.44
0005.55                   5.55
00000000000000000006.66   6.66
```

I fully support not using table access mode and in general I'm in favor of pushing work onto the source system but this seems like a low effort if the source system doesn't allow for conversion or if you have to resort to mucking about with strings.